# Apollo Client generates an empty API.swift file

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to use apollo client with iOS and I cant.

I did all steps described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html#Manual-integration) but no results at all because the file is empty. The only change I did was removing the query param and now looks like this:

> $APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate
>   --schema=schema.json API.swift

Does anybody has had this issue before?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you the schema.json is present, contains schema information and is at the root of your Xcode project. It's possible that it's looking for the file, not finding and therefore not generating the API.Swift file.