# check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, apollo-client

I'm trying to run an app for a client, and I keep going through this error:

[image]

The app is using a Cocoapod called Apollo, fully updated. I'm using Xcode 13.3, on a 2018 Macbook Pro

I've tried some solutions like:

- Reinstall the pod (deleting the line in Podfile, updating, adding again and cleaning the build)
- Change the script on Build Phases to match this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54735720/check-and-run-apollo-codegen-sh-for-apollo-not-working)
- And I searched and found schema files like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806341/apollo-client-generates-an-empty-api-swift-file)
- I've also read the Apollo documentation and found nothing wrong with the code or scripts in the app.

In my target BuildPhases/Run Script, I have the following code:

```
APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH="$(eval find $FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS -name "Apollo.framework" -maxdepth 1)"
if [ -z "$APOLLO__FRAMEWORK_PATH" ]; then
echo "error: Couldn't find Apollo.framework in FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS; make sure to add the framework to your project."
exit 1
fi

cd "${SCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/Api/PrivateAPI"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate --queries="$(find . -name '*.graphql')" --passthroughCustomScalars --schema=schemaPrivate.json PrivateAPI.swift
cd "${SCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/Api/PublicAPI"
$APOLLO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/check-and-run-apollo-cli.sh codegen:generate --queries="$(find . -name '*.graphql')" --passthroughCustomScalars --schema=schemaPublic.json PublicAPI.swift
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Since the code was made in 2018, seems like the Apollo pod had some changes. I changed my BuildPhases/Run Script to this code, like the Apollo documentation asks:

```
if [ $ACTION = "indexbuild"]; then exit 0; fi

SCRIPT_PATH="${PODS_ROOT}/Apollo/scripts"

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/API/PublicAPI"
"${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./****.graphql --localSchemaFile="schemaPublic.json" PublicAPI.swift

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}/API/PrivateAPI"
"${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./****.graphql --localSchemaFile="schemaPrivate.json" PrivateAPI.swift
```

That worked for these error.